# The best library for mapping Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, github-mantle

as a developer I face with processing data each day. The common thing that I need to process the raw data to the object (NSManagedObject). So I am using AFNetworking for getting data from the remote server and as a result of AFNetworking work I have a data that can be represented by NSDictionary. So the main thing that can take a lot of work it is converting this raw data to concrete data models. So there are many libraries in the Internet that can do this hard work for us:

[MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) `MagicalImport`

[Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle)

[EasyMapping](https://github.com/lucasmedeirosleite/EasyMapping)

So as a new in mapping I want to know which library is the best for my purposes. Maybe you can suggest another one as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the libraries you mentioned have different purposes:

**MagicalRecord** - simplifies common Core Data operations (fetching, inserting, deleting, setting up the stack, etc.). <s>It does not handle mapping JSON or any other format to Core Data models.</s> *Correction thanks to @casademora*: MagicalRecord can handle imports with custom mappings using the steps described [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aajFwmu7XA0sJ%3awww.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl). That said, MagicalRecord is a rather large library to use just for this piece of functionality.

**Mantle** - greatly reduces boilerplate for model objects in Objective-C (automatic implementations of `NSCoding`, `NSCopying`, `-isEqual:`/`-hash`, etc.). Includes adapters like `MTLJSONAdapter` and `MTLManagedObjectAdapter` for converting between representations of model obejcts. This sounds like it's the best fit for what you're trying to achieve. If you implement both the `MTLJSONSerializing` and `MTLManagedObjectSerializing` protocols on your `MTLModel` subclass you will be able to turn `NSDictionary` responses from the web API (presumably JSON data) into Core Data model objects.

**EasyMapping** - I haven't used this library myself, but it looks like its provides a small subset of Mantle's functionality purely for converting between various model representations, except that it uses mapping models (`EKObjectMapping`) instead of subclassing a base model class. The disadvantages of using this library would be that it doesn't handle any of the other Objective-C model object boilerplate for you like Mantle does.

Out of the 3 libraries mentioned, I think Mantle would probably be the best fit for what you described. Another option is to use [RestKit](http://restkit.org/), which provides tighter REST API/Core Data integration than any of these libraries, but is significantly harder to use and debug.

Comment: thank you for detail answer. is this right understanding like mapping and import as the same things?

Comment: MagicalRecord does handle more complex cases, it merely starts with the assumption that your external data and data model match 1:1, and you can define exceptions.

Comment: @casademora Sorry about that! I took another look found these constants: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalDataImport.h#L10-L17. Where do you pass in these options (so I can edit and clarify my post)?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Mapping is just one part of the import process, which could involve other steps like value transformation.

Comment: I've documented the import process on cimgf.com here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ajFwmu7XA0sJ:www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl

Comment: Thanks, edited. Would be nice to link to that on the MagicalRecord repo so it's easier to find.

Comment: MagicalRecord does more than mapping, it also allows you to use easy one liners as wrappers for interacting with core data. These are actually the functions I use; I don't use the mapping function of Magical Record since my imported data and model are not 1:1, and often need transformations.  I don't know if Mantle and EasyMapping have all these extra's as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need close Core Data integration you should look at RestKit (http://restkit.org)
If you do not - I suggest EasyMapping. It is very easy and powerful enough for almost all situations. It is also not requires to subclass your classes from framework class (like MTLModel in Mantle)

Comment: It's worth noting that Mantle 2.0 probably won't require subclassing `MTLModel`, if you implement the `MTLModel` protocol. It's certainly a fair point for Mantle 1.x though.